# how to start asp.net mvc 4 web application in a refresh/initial state

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I'm new in asp.net world. I'm building asp.net mvc 4 web application. It has basic http authentication. At the beginning it ask user name and password. After authentication it start some view. During debug if successfully authenticated and continue debugging to some other view/controller. If I stop debugging or app crashes. For the next debug run it never prompt me for authentication. It takes to the view which comes after authentication. I suppose it caches my authentication from previous run. I try to find solution from net and found many suggestion such as :-

1. Restart iis
2. Remove cache files from c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
3. Modify web.config and rebuild, then lunch.
4. Remove browser cache.
5. Even restart pc doesn't help-

I tried all nothing is working. As I'm new I'm not sure is my web.config file has right configuration for HTTP basic authentication. Here it is:-

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" >

      </forms>
    </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

My environment windows 7, iis 7.5, visual studio 2012. Please advise me how can force authentication every time or start as in initial state. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the browser cookie that is letting you in as it's still valid for your application. Clear your browser cookies or start an in-private session.

Comment: How do I start ie in-private session from visual studio 2012?

Comment: You can't, it's a browser feature.

Comment: Delete browser cookie worked fine. It is tedious/boring to delete cookie every time from browser (long process many clicks required). But Is there a way to speedup development process?

Comment: You can probably just try to log out of the application.